# How to implement a DrawLine function ?

Tags: android, image-processing, drawing, android-canvas, draw

Question : Is there any better way to implement a function that draws line on the screen other than drawing circles on the input points ?

Details : I am trying to write a function which basically will draw a line.However the line will not be a regular colored line. This line will let user to copy pixels from one image to another trough that line , you can think It like "history brush" or "stamp" on Photoshop . My first thought was just get the points and draw circles on each point. Which is working but not smooth and have some bugs. The first problem is it is not working if user sweep his finger too fast. I thought it would solve problem if i can fill the dots between two points and then draw the line which is kind of work but this time drawing gets very slow. One other problem is that it never looks smooth.

Comment: Do you mean a freehand line, or a point-to-point straight line? If the latter, this is simple by stroking a canvas path, right?

Comment: @ Phrogz i mean freehand line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't the [BitmapShader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapShader.html) what you're looking for?

Comment: Wow ! I didn't know we can do this. Thank you very much. It made everything so easier . Thank you again !

Answer (score 3):

[Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)